# Income percentile ranks

Tags: probability

Income percentile ranks are numbers from $0$ to $100$ that indicate where you sit in the income distribution — for example, $75$ would mean you earn more income than three quarters of people, but less than the top quarter.   Let's assume a child's expected income percentile is a linear function of their parents' income percentile. It turns out the intercept is enough to pin down the slope. Do you see why? If the intercept is $20$ — which means the lowest-income parents have children who end up at the $20^{th}$ percentile, on average — what is the slope?

This problem is from an app called probability puzzles.

My approach: I realised $y=ax+b$ could be the line for child but we don't have any information about the slope. We know that percentile is uniformly distributed between $0$ and $100$ so expected value is $50$ but I don't see how to proceed from here. Help!

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with your linear function: $y=ax+b$, where $x$ is the ith parents' income percentile. And $y$ is the child's expected income percentile. Then the crucial information are

> If the intercept is 20 — which means the lowest-income parents have
> children who end up at the 20th percentile, on average.

This give us the equation $y(0)=20$. A child cannot end up below the 20th percentile: $y(0)=a\cdot 0+b=b=20$.

Then the highest income parents percentile ($x=100$) can have children who end up at the highest income percentile ($y=100$), on average. It cannot be more, since the codomain of the percentile is between $0$ and $100$. Thus the equation is

$$100=a\cdot 100+20$$

Finally, calculate the value of $a$.

Comment: This answer doesn't match with the given answer. I have accepted it though since I find the explanation plausible but maybe could you try thinking from a different perspective? I am too trying the same.

Comment: @Charlie What is the given answer?

Comment: I don't know. The app shows correct if it is correct else it just shows incorrect!

Comment: @Charlie Mmh, then we cannot use it as a hint.

Answer (score 0):

*Hint:* we know that the expected value of percentile is $50$, so $E(y)=E(x)=50$. What does that tell you about $a$?

Comment: Maybe just 0, you mean?

Comment: @Charlie Not 0. By linearity of expectation, E(y)=aE(x)+b. Since we know b=20, we should be able to find what a is.

Comment: yep got it, thanks